Почему слово Масло склоняется?
Нарицательные имена существительные на -о, -у, -е, -ю, -и, -э и ударную -а не склоняются.
Но почему, например, склоняется слово масло? По какому правилу ориентироваться?

Приведите ссылку на это правило. Возможно, там речь идет не о всех нарицательных существительных.  А "масло" уж точно не имеется в виду.

Масло не склоняется, потому что это исконно русское слово. не было у нас раньше привычки не склонять слова.  И ориентироваться здесь нужно не по правилу, а по словарю. // Но сам вопрос интересен, предлагаю участникам проявить к нему внимание.  Голос от меня.

Имеется ввиду фамилия-прозвище Масло? Например, Борис Масло? Позовите Бориса Масло к телефону?
